# Run Matlab with a desktop launcher

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher, scripts, matlab

I'm trying to make a desktop launcher for Matlab in order to run it from the desktop.
This is how my desktop entry looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_AU]=/home/userA/Pictures/matlab.png
Name[en_AU]=Matlab
Exec=/media/d/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/matlab
Name=Matlab
Icon=/home/userA/Pictures/matlab.png
```

But when I run it, matlab start page appears for a second then disappears, this happened to me before when trying to run it from the folder itself, and I figured out that I need to `sudo`,  so I need to modify my desktop entry `exec` command so that it runs matlab without asking everytime for password. So if anyone could please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to run Matlab as a superuser. What you do need though is the `-desktop` option:

```
Exec=/media/d/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/matlab -desktop
```